# How to examine ruby processes for performance problems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-debug

I have an issue with a rails worker that is consuming extreme amounts of processor time.  Oddly I have not been able to trace it out so far.  I've tried to use New Relic, however I can't seem to trace it down within the worker itself.

How can I profile and really explore performance issues in detail so as to find precise locations of performance problems such as this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Ruby-Prof](https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof)? It's easy to use and seems to return accurate numbers. (Of course it's hard to argue with it when running an app that's busy.)